# WebStorm: no colours in output of bash script file

Tags: bash, intellij-idea, terminal, phpstorm, webstorm

When I type and run commands inside IDE's built-in terminal output has colors

[image: terminal]

But if I'll **put that commands inside `.sh` file** and will run that file with `Run/Debug`, the output would be with no colours:

[image: run/debug]

**Question**:

Is it exist a way to enable colour output for the `.sh` files?

P.S. I'm on `macos`

Comment: Do you use BashSupport plug-in to run `.sh` scripts from the IDE?

Comment: @CrazyCoder Yes I do, it's turned on by default anyway

Comment: In this case you may want to file a ticket to the [plug-in issue tracker](https://github.com/jansorg/BashSupport/issues) and ask the developer to add ANSI colors support for the output. See the [relevant comment](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-139141#comment=27-978868).